# Getting Range.Find to work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project for work and I need help changing this code to work with my current worksheet. In my "Registration" worksheet I have an area where I'm trying to type in the "Athlete" name and it will pull the information from the "Master List" worksheet.

***Update*** Here is the original workbook that this coding is coming from. I'm trying to get this coding to work on my new work book because I'm using two worksheets instead of one.

[image: Original Workbook]

Here is the old code that I have but am unable to configure it to work with this new workbook since I'm working off of two worksheets instead of one.

```
Sub Update()
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
Set rngSearch = Range("B18:B150")
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=Range("B12").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, 
LookAt:=xlPart)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Please recheck name"
Range("B12").Value = " "
Exit Sub

End If

'Range("B12:O12").Copy
'Range("B" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
'Range("B12:O12").ClearContents
For a = 5 To 14
If Cells(12, a) = "X" Or Cells(12, a) = "X" Then
Cells(rngFound.Row, a).Value = "X"
Else
Cells(rngFound.Row, a).Value = " "
End If
Next
Range("B12:O12").ClearContents

Range("C12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,2,FALSE))"
Range("D12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,3,FALSE))"
Range("E12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,4,FALSE))"
Range("F12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,5,FALSE))"
Range("G12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,6,FALSE))"
Range("H12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,7,FALSE))"
Range("I12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,8,FALSE))"
Range("J12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,9,FALSE))"
Range("K12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,10,FALSE))"
Range("L12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,11,FALSE))"
Range("M12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,12,FALSE))"
Range("N12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,13,FALSE))"
Range("O12").Formula = "=IF($B12="" "","" "",VLOOKUP($B12,$B18:$O150,14,FALSE))"

End Sub
```

*** Update ***
I was able to find a Macro that needs to be updated as well. This was hiding in a different Module.

```
Sub values()
'
'values Macro
'

'
    Range("B12:O12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B18").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Here are a couple images of the new worksheets I am working on.

[Update Athlete: A29:O29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r89Pz.png)

["Master List"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PMz.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. It might help to read [ask].

Comment: You should attach your code here instead of taking a screenshot like that.

Comment: @John Coleman: I tried to copy and paste the code, but there was a formatting error i was getting when I tried to post the code. That's why I screenshot it and posted it that way.

Comment: Copy/paste the code into the edit window, highlight the code, and then hit `Ctrl+K`? In general, people on Stack Overflow hate images of code. Nobody is going to bother to *type* the code, so why bother to even try to answer it? You can't experiment with it without undue effort.

Comment: @John Coleman: Thank you, I am new to this forum site and I am still learning. I was able to figure it out.

Comment: @I'mFromAlaska No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your get data file (the one with button) try remove any merge column (A&B). Do the same for "master list"
As you might seen, you input name in cell A29 so you need to change B12 -> A29

```
Sub Update()
Dim rngSearch As Range, rngFound As Range
'Search range: Change sheets and range 
Set rngSearch = Sheets("Master list").Range("A3:O150")
' You type in cell A29 then search by cell A29, not B12
Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=Range("A29").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Please recheck name"
    Range("A29").Value = " "
    Exit Sub
End If
'I think this is meaningless
'Range("B12:O12").Copy
'Range("B" & rngFound.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'Range("B12:O12").ClearContents
'For a = 5 To 14
'If Cells(12, a) = "X" Or Cells(12, a) = "X" Then
'Cells(rngFound.Row, a).Value = "X"
'Else
'Cells(rngFound.Row, a).Value = " "
'End If
'Next
'Range("B12:O12").ClearContents

'You should pay attention to this as this is where your data will show: Row 29 from column B to O ( I assume that you remove the merge cell A&B)
' Source :master list
Range("B29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,2,FALSE))"
Range("C29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,3,FALSE))"
Range("D29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,4,FALSE))"
Range("E29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,5,FALSE))"
Range("F29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,6,FALSE))"
Range("G29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,7,FALSE))"
Range("H29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,8,FALSE))"
Range("I29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,9,FALSE))"
Range("J29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,10,FALSE))"
Range("K29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,11,FALSE))"
Range("L29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,12,FALSE))"
Range("M29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,13,FALSE))"
Range("N29").Formula = "=IF($A29="","",VLOOKUP($A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,14,FALSE))"

End Sub
```

*update* for the values sub

```
    Sub values()
    '
    'values Macro
    '

    ' Edit your target sheet here:
With Sheets("target sheet name")
' Avoid select, it will slow down your code
        .Range("B12:O12").Copy
        .Range("B18").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    end with
    End Sub
```

p/s: might be this one is all you need:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A29,'Master list'!$A3:$O150,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: updated answer as you finally able to paste your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to find a Macro that would need to be corrected. Would you be able to look at it and let me know how it could be changed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Without knowing where and purpose of that function(context), it's hard to give you any recommendation. Btw, you could try to modify those "Range" with a parent sheet object like "Sheets("Master List").Range("B12:O12")" .  Be careful, it's values procedure, not value method which belongs to Range object.

Comment: All this coding was from a one worksheet. I'm trying to re-code it to work in a two worksheet coding. I'll see if I can upload an image of the original workbook this coding was coming from. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I tried entering the code with nothing happening. It might be me not inputting it in correctly. It's also harder to explain than actually seeing. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, if you updated your post then you should comment,.. so that others know you have update the post. I see your problem now. It's pretty basic so that I did not pay attention. I will edit my post.

Comment: In my opinion, just put the Vlookup there, no need VBA.